# Why do I get an error when I put a question inside an if statement

Tags: python, input, syntax, conditional-statements

I use Python and I’m a beginner. I keep getting an error with this code:

```
    if(answer == “yes”):
      question = input(“What do you like painting?”)
    else:
      print(“May I suggest sculpting?”)
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the error to know how to help you. Without seeing the full code two things come to mind.

1. is answer defined? In this code the variable "answer" is never defined. If you are hoping to get the input from your question "what do you like painting", that will be returned to the variable "question" once the user inputs it.
2. Your quotation marks look a bit odd. I'm guessing that is just from how you typed it into stackoverflow, but if not try replacing them with either `'` or `"`

This works for me:

```
answer = input("Do you like painting?")

if(answer == "yes"):
  question = input("What do you like painting?")
else:
  print("May I suggest sculpting?")
```

As does this:

```
if(input("What do you like painting?") == "yes"):
  print("May I suggest sculpting?")
```

Comment: Modularizer, I have my code exactly as your first example. The quotation marks that I have are just how I typed it into stack overflow and answer is also defined.

Comment: Interesting? What does the error message say?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of that could cause isses is indentation

Comment: Actually it was the indentation. Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

**In python you have to Initialization objects ,  when you using object  >>> **

```
answer = input("Do you like painting?")
  if answer  == ('Yes' or 'yes' or 'YES'):
     question = input("What do you like painting?")
      print(question)
  else answer  == ('No' or 'no' or 'NO'):
       print("May I suggest sculpting?")
```